# Lambda Deleter in VC 2013 vs 2015

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, lambda, visual-studio-2015

I am moving some old code from VC 2013 to 2015.

The simplified code below works fine in VC 2013, but fails in 2015 with:

*`error C2664: 'void main::<lambda_da721648e605a5fd45c9a3fb8c3d06f6>::operator ()(main::D *&) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'main::D *' to 'main::D *&'`*

I am not looking for a solution, but for an explanation on what and why changed.

Thank you.

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
  class D{};

  auto mydel = []( D*&p ) { delete p; p = 0; };

  std::unique_ptr< D, decltype(mydel) > up( new D );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apparently the internals of `unique_ptr` used to always call the deleter with an lvalue `pointer`, but now calls it at least once with an rvalue `pointer`.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same settings with both versions? This might be related to MSVC's infamous extension that allows binding an rvalue to a non-const lvalue reference. Maybe they disable this by default in VS2015?

Comment: @Praetorian I am using the default settings for both versions. I do not know how to change this option.

Comment: @ZDF You can change it in `Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> Disable Language Extensions`

Comment: @Rakete1111 Off/On made no difference.

Comment: @ZDF Then it isn't related to some weird VS language extension :)

Comment: Is `struct mydeltype{ void operator(D *&p) {delete p; p = nullptr;}};` really that hard to write?

Comment: @NicolBolas Not at all.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is this supposed to accomplish? `up == nullptr` will be `true` *anyway* when `up` no longer owns an object.

Comment: @KyleStrand It is a simplified version of the original code. As far as I know `~unique_ptr` does not assign null to the underlying pointer.

Comment: @ZDF The underlying pointer is an implementation detail. [`get()` returns `nullptr` if there is no managed object.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get). And since `unique_ptr` is guaranteed to be the size of a pointer, the most obvious way to implement tracking for whether there is a managed object or not would be to simply set the underlying pointer to `nullptr`.

Comment: @ZDF Also, wait, you want to ensure that the value of the underlying pointer is null after *the unique-pointer destructor* has been called? That doesn't make sense; there is no "underlying pointer" once it's been *destroyed*!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of deleter must be callable with an argument of type `pointer`.  In your case `pointer` is `D*`.  Your deleter is not callable with this, but instead requires an argument of type `pointer&`, so your code was ill-formed with no diagnostic required.

In addition, `decltype(mydel)` is a lambda object type.  Lambda objects have no default constructor, even stateless ones.  Your unique pointer creating code:

```
std::unique_ptr< D, decltype(mydel) > up( new D );
```

is thus ill-formed.  The correct verson would be:

```
std::unique_ptr< D, decltype(mydel) > up( new D, mydel );
```

This is annoying.

Odds are 2013's lambda had a zero argument constructor lying around, in violation of the standard.  MSVC2013 was only nominally a C++11 compiler.

In addition, it probably only passed in lvalue `D*` types.  It is permitted to do this, but it is not required to do it by the standard.

---

While this is not the focus of your question, I will note we can clean this up in C++17 as follows:

```
template<auto* pfunc>
struct stateless {
  template<class...Args>
  decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&...args)const {
    return std::invoke( pfunc, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  }
};

int main() {
  class D{};

  auto mydel = []( D*p ) { delete p; };

  std::unique_ptr< D, stateless<+mydel> > up( new D );

  return 0;
}
```

but MSVC2015 doesn't support this (maybe if you requested the latest standard in a later update it might).

C++17 code not tested on a C++17 compiler, as none actually exist yet (There are some C++1z compilers, and some might actually be able to compile the above, but I don't have them lying around.)

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not wrong, the problem is that you declare `up` as a `std:unique_ptr` with a deleter of type `decltype(mydel)` but you don't pass `mydel` to it.

The correct call should be

```
std::unique_ptr< D, decltype(mydel) > up( new D, mydel );
```

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr), your constructor

> Requires that Deleter is DefaultConstructible and that construction
>   does not throw an exception.

and, if I'm not wrong, `decltype(mydel)` isn't default constructible (how could it be?)

The right question, I suppose, isn't "why VC 2015 give an error?" but "why VC 2013 compile?"

Comment: You will still get the same error. I am not looking for a solution, but for an explanation (I  have already fixed the code). I suspect that the explanation has to do with a "better" implementation of the standard. I am not that smart to find it by myself.

Comment: @ZDF Without passing in the lambda your code wasn't standards compliant, as `mydel` should have no default constructor.  There could be other problems as well, but this does answer why your code was ill-formed before and the new compiler was right to reject it.

Comment: @Yakk, I agree. But why 2013 had not problem with it?

Comment: @ZDF Compiler bug probably :)

Comment: @ZDF - modified my answer trying to respond your question (but Yakk is clearer).

Comment: @Rakete1111 - do you mean a bug in VC 2013 ?

Comment: @max66 Most likely. OP's code is ill-formed, so it shouldn't even compile

Comment: max66, I would check both answers, but it is not possible. Thank you.

Comment: @ZDF - You've done the right thing: my answer is a subset of the Yakk's one; and the Yakk's answer is clearer than mine.